# Facebook Login with Swift crash issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, swift

Since many times i did Objective-C coding but recently i am moving to swift. It look very new for for me.
In My application i need to integrate Facebook while integrating i feel that Same code of block works nicely in Objective-C but in Swift it crashes inside Clouser while creating Facebook Session

See Attached image. It’s Headache now. Your help will be appreciate.

[image]

```
FBSession.activeSession().setStateChangeHandler({(currentSession:FBSession!, stateOfSession: FBSessionState!, sessionError: NSError!) in
        self.sessionStateChanged(currentSession, state: stateOfSession, error: sessionError)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
FBSession.activeSession().setStateChangeHandler { (session: FBSession!, state: FBSessionState,error:  NSError!) -> Void in
        self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
    }
```

It worked for me.